# How good is ApnsPHP?

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

I want to build a push server that can handle a heavy load of push notifications that it needs to send. I was wondering if ApnsPHP (http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/) is the right chice for me, or if I should build it using some other language.

Any help or pointers would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

APNS-PHP works out of the box on Snow Leopard! But I can't get it working on Ubuntu 8.04 or 10.04

Answer (score 0):

It will work on Ubuntu 10.04 and PHP 5.3.2 after installing libssh2-php.

But only with Sandbox.

On Production i must increase Timeout and then I get, that message was send, but never reveived on my iPhone.

Aro